# What is the difference between terminating an Oracle sql statement with semicolon or with a slash on the next line?

Tags: oracle

The following two queries seem to be equivalent when executed in sql*plus:

1.

```
select * from user_tables;
```

2.

```
select * from user_tables
/
```

Is there any difference between both versions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no difference for a single SQL statement.  The '/' character on its own line tells SQL*Plus to execute the command in the buffer.  You can use the semicolon at the end of most SQL statements as a shorthand for the '/'.  If you want to execute a PL/SQL block or to execute a handful of SQL statements like `CREATE TYPE`, however, you need to use the '/'

```
SQL> begin
  2    null;
  3  end;
  4  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> create type foo as object (
  2    col1 number,
  3    col2 number );
  4  /

Type created.
```

Different tools may have slightly different conventions for how you execute multiple SQL and PL/SQL statements in a script so be aware that this is SQL*Plus specific.

Comment: Is it analogous then to SQL Server's `GO`?  (Basically, a batch separator.)

Comment: @NickChammas - More or less, yes.

Answer (score 5):

And besides what Justin mentioned -- because the `/` runs whatever's in the buffer, it can also be used after editing the previous command, or even just to run the same command multiple times.

If you call `ed` in sqlplus, it'll try to write a temp file `AFIEDT.BUF` in your current directory, and then bring up an editor [(vi, notepad, etc.),](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Plus_FAQ#I.27m_unable_to_edit_files._What_is_wrong.3F) for you to edit the last command sent.  One you're exited the editor, you use `/` to send the modified buffer.

Comment: I get nostalgic http://bkriszio.blogspot.com/2006/11/minimal-sqlplus-clone-in-ironpython.html.