# Why does SQL*PLUS need a slash after CREATE TYPE?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, user-defined-type

I just had the problem that I defined a Type and tested it in TOAD and all was OK. But running under SQL*PLUS it threw an error.

Example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MyType AS OBJECT (
    Item1 NUMBER,
    Item2 NUMBER
);
```

For some reason I have to add a slash here

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MyType AS OBJECT (
    Item1 NUMBER,
    Item2 NUMBER
);
/
```

To me it looks similar to a Create Table statement, which doesn't require a slash. 
I find it rather confusing. I know *how* it works, but can anyone explain why this design decision was made?

Comment: answered in : http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1305/what-is-the-difference-between-terminating-an-oracle-sql-statement-with-semicolon

Comment: No the question **Why** is not answered there. It seems to be an arbitrary design decision of the sql*plus team.

Comment: There is a great answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10207695/1568658

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you need a `/` after a PL/SQL block in SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> begin
  2     null;
  3  end;
  4  -- here you need a /
  5  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
```

This is so SQL*Plus knows you are done with your statement (which could include intermediate, non-terminating `;`).

SQL types may include PL/SQL code, therefore the SQL*Plus devs decided that you need a `/` in all cases after a CREATE TYPE:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE t AS OBJECT (
  2     x NUMBER,
  3     MEMBER PROCEDURE setx(p_x NUMBER)
  4  );
  5  /

Type created

SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY t AS
  2     MEMBER PROCEDURE setx (p_x NUMBER) IS
  3     BEGIN
  4        x := p_x;
  5     END;
  6  END;
  7  /

Type body created
```

**Note**: you also need a `/` after you define a procedure, a package or a package body (for the same reason).