# Oracle: when do I use a slash between statements?

Tags: oracle

I have finally traced a dreaded `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.` error to not putting a slash between statements.

If I attempt to run this:

```sql
SELECT 200 AS integer_result FROM DUAL;
SELECT 200 AS integer_result FROM DUAL;
```

everything is fine. If I try this:

```sql
SELECT 200/7 AS integer_result FROM DUAL;
SELECT 200/7 AS integer_result FROM DUAL;
```

I get

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.

I can fix it by including a slash:

```sql
SELECT 200/7 AS integer_result FROM DUAL;
/
SELECT 200/7 AS integer_result FROM DUAL;
```

Obviously division has confused Oracle, the poor thing. I have never seen this in any other DBMS, but we live to learn.

What is the rule for adding slashes between statements and why?

The question at [What is the difference between terminating an Oracle sql statement with semicolon or with a slash on the next line?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1305/what-is-the-difference-between-terminating-an-oracle-sql-statement-with-semicolo) has some information, but the accepted answer basically says there’s no difference, which is clearly not right in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It is your environment, not the database. Above commands work as expected.

```
SQL> SELECT 200/7 AS integer_result FROM DUAL;

INTEGER_RESULT
--------------
    28.5714286

SQL> !cat 1.sql
SELECT 200/7 AS integer_result FROM DUAL;
SELECT 200/7 AS integer_result FROM DUAL;

SQL> @1.sql

INTEGER_RESULT
--------------
    28.5714286


INTEGER_RESULT
--------------
    28.5714286

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, and I am looking into this. I can verify that it’s OK on __Oracle SQL Developer__. The confusing part is that the `ORA-00933` error is obviously coming from the DBMS.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify which tool you use, but - that's something that happens in e.g. SQL*Plus when SQL terminator character is set to slash.

```
SQL> set sqlterminator /
SQL> SELECT 200/7 AS integer_result FROM DUAL;
  2  /
SELECT 200/7 AS integer_result FROM DUAL;
                                        *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended


SQL>
```

If that's your case as well, set it to default character - semicolon:

```
SQL> set sqlterminator ;
SQL> SELECT 200/7 AS integer_result FROM DUAL;

INTEGER_RESULT
--------------
    28.5714286

SQL>
```

---

As of *original* question you asked: semicolon terminates *one statement*, slash terminates PL/SQL block **or** (again - in SQL*Plus and similar tools) - re-executes previous command.

Semicolon, terminating one statement:

```
SQL> SELECT 200/7 AS integer_result FROM DUAL;

INTEGER_RESULT
--------------
    28.5714286
```

In PL/SQL, semicolon terminates statement (e.g. line #2), while slash terminates the whole procedure (line #4):

```
SQL> begin
  2    null;
  3  end;
  4  /
```

Without slash, if you keep hitting the ENTER key, you'd get bunch of *empty lines* until you get bored (or - finally - hit the slash):

```
SQL> begin
  2    null;
  3  end;
  4
  5
  6

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Re-executing previous statement:

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
---------
02-MAR-23

SQL> /

SYSDATE
---------
02-MAR-23

SQL>
```